# mysqli_query insert and update within array not working

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, sql-update, insert-update

Hey everyone I am trying to run two insert statements and than finally run an update statement within a php array but it seems not to be working correctly. I realize this code has some problems for instance escaping html data before inserting it into the database isn't ideal however i will fix that later the only thing I am concerned about is the insert and update statements. The following is the code I am using:

This is the job data array being built.

```
if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    $datetime =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $submissionId = rand(10000,99999);

    $req_data = array(
    'itemId' => $i_san,
    'itemName' => $_POST['itemName'],
    'submissionId' => $submissionId,
    'username' => $_SESSION['username'],
    'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
    'subDate' => $datetime,
    'wistiaId' => $_SESSION['wistiaId']
    );
    add_DCRequests($req_data);//INSERT INTO `DCrequests`

    // === Sanatize inputs === //
    $text_1_raw = $_POST['textOne'];
    $text_1_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_1_raw);
    //$text_one = utf8_encode("Ñ");
    $text_one = htmlentities(trim($text_1_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_2_raw = $_POST['textTwo'];
    $text_2_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_2_raw);
    $text_two = htmlentities(trim($text_2_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8' );

    $text_3_raw = $_POST['textThree'];
    $text_3_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_3_raw);
    $text_three = htmlentities(trim($text_3_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_4_raw = $_POST['textFour'];
    $text_4_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_4_raw);
    $text_four = htmlentities(trim($text_4_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_5_raw = $_POST['textFive'];
    $text_5_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_5_raw);
    $text_five = htmlentities(trim($text_5_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_6_raw = $_POST['textSix'];
    $text_6_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_6_raw);
    $text_six = htmlentities(trim($text_6_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_7_raw = $_POST['textSeven'];
    $text_7_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_7_raw);
    $text_seven = htmlentities(trim($text_7_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_8_raw = $_POST['textEight'];
    $text_8_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_8_raw);
    $text_eight = htmlentities(trim($text_8_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_9_raw = $_POST['textNine'];
    $text_9_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_9_raw);
    $text_nine = htmlentities(trim($text_9_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_10_raw = $_POST['textTen'];
    $text_10_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_10_raw);
    $text_ten = htmlentities(trim($text_10_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_11_raw = $_POST['textEleven'];
    $text_11_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_11_raw);
    $text_eleven = htmlentities(trim($text_11_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $text_12_raw = $_POST['textTwelve'];
    $text_12_noQuotes = str_replace('"',"'",$text_12_raw);
    $text_twelve = htmlentities(trim($text_12_noQuotes) , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');

    $aep = escape_data($_POST['aep']);
    $output = escape_data($_POST['output']) . "_" . $_POST['subId'];
    $output_scrub = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]/', "", $output);
    $rendStatus = "ready";

    //parse out 3 items from POST target (display shape matrix | disp w | disp h)
    $item = escape_data($_POST['target']);
    $get_target_w_h = explode('|', $item);
    $targ = escape_data($get_target_w_h[0]);
    $w = escape_data($get_target_w_h[1]);
    $h = escape_data($get_target_w_h[2]);
    $matrix = $w ."x". $h;

    $BGColor = escape_data($_POST['hex']);
    $bg_scrub = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', "", $BGColor);
    $c1 = escape_data($_POST['hex2']);
    $c1_scrub = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', "", $c1);
    $c2 = escape_data($_POST['hex3']);
    $c2_scrub = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', "", $c2);
    $c3 = escape_data($_POST['hex4']);
    $c3_scrub = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', "", $c3);
    // if user is banner attach value = 2
    if($_SESSION['userLevel'] == 5){$attach = 2;}else{$attach = 0;}

    $show = escape_data($_POST['hide']);

    if($show === '1'){
        $show_1_val = '{{on}}';
        $show_2_val = '{{off}}';
        $show_3_val = '{{off}}';
    }elseif($show === '2'){
        $show_1_val = '{{off}}';
        $show_2_val = '{{on}}';
        $show_3_val = '{{off}}';
    }elseif($show === '3'){
        $show_1_val = '{{off}}';
        $show_2_val = '{{off}}';
        $show_3_val = '{{on}}';
    }

    $show1_scrub = preg_replace('/[^a-z\{}]/', "", $show1);
    $show2 = escape_data($_POST['HideShowLayer2']);
    $show2_scrub = preg_replace('/[^a-z\{}]/', "", $show2);
    $show3 = escape_data($_POST['HideShowLayer3']);
    $show3_scrub = preg_replace('/[^a-z\{}]/', "", $show3);

    $still = escape_data($_POST['HideShowLayer1']);
    $stillFrame = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.{}]/', "", $custStillFrame);

    if($target_file1 != ""){
        $image1 = "https://www.test.com/ce/". escape_data($target_file1);}
    else{ 
        $image1 = "";
    }

    if($target_file2 != ""){
        $image2 = "https://www.test.com/ce/". escape_data($target_file2);}
    else{ 
        $image2 = "";
    }

    if($target_file3 != ""){
        $image3 = "https://www.test.com/ce/". escape_data($target_file3);}
    else{ 
        $image3 = "";
    }
    $completion_date="";
    $DCjobsFileId="";

    $itemName = escape_data($_POST['itemName']);
    $estimatedTime = $currentRendTotal + $custEstRenderTime;
    $mydate = date('m/d/Y');

    // === Data to insert into the table === //
    $job_data = array(
        //'bannerToken' => $bannerToken,
        'attach' => $attach,
        'full-date' => $mydate,
        'aep' => $aep,
        'target' => $targ,
        'output' => $output_scrub,
        'itemName' => $itemName,
        'render-status' => $rendStatus,
        'est_render_time' => $_POST['renderEst'],
        'frameNumber' => $stillFrame,
        'CustomerName' => $_SESSION['first_name'],
        'CustomerEmail' => $_SESSION['email'],
        'CustomerKey' => $_SESSION['wistiaId'],
        'submissionDate' => $datetime,
        'submissionId' => $_POST['subId'],
        'itemId' => $custItemId,
        'matrix' => $matrix,
        'fileformat' => $_POST['format'],
        'BGColor' => $bg_scrub,
        'ColorOne' => $c1_scrub,
        'ColorTwo' => $c2_scrub,
        'ColorThree' => $c3_scrub,

        'Text-One' => $text_one,
        'Text-Two' => $text_two,
        'Text-Three' => $text_three,
        'Text-Four' => $text_four,
        'Text-Five' => $text_five,
        'Text-Six' => $text_six,
        'Text-Seven' => $text_seven,
        'Text-Eight' => $text_eight,
        'Text-Nine' => $text_nine,
        'Text-Ten' => $text_ten,
        'Text-Eleven' => $text_eleven,
        'Text-Twelve' => $text_twelve,

        'HideShowOne' => $show_1_val,
        'HideShowTwo' => $show_2_val,
        'HideShowThree' => $show_3_val,

        'ImageUploadOne' => $image1,
        'ImageUploadTwo' => $image2,
        'ImageUploadThree' => $image3,
        'completion_date' => "CRAP",
        'DCjobsFileId' => "CRAP"

    );
    add_jobs($job_data);//"INSERT INTO `DCjobs` and INSERT INTO `DCjobsArchive`
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header('Location: https://www.test.com/ce/thanks.php?est='.$estimatedTime);
    exit();

}elseif(empty($errors) === false){
    $reportErrors = "<br /><br /><br />Oops, the following errors occured: <br />" . $errors . "<br /><br /> Please click <a href=\"customize.php\">here</a> to try again. <br /><br />";
}

?>
```

This is the function that inserts and updates the data from the jobdata array

```
function add_jobs($job_data){
    global $db_conx;
    array_walk($job_data, 'array_sanitize');

    $jobfields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($job_data)) . '`';
    $jobdata = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $job_data) . '\'';

    mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO `DCjobs` ($jobfields) VALUES ($jobdata)");
    mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO `DCjobsArchive` ($jobfields) VALUES ($jobdata)");

    $selectmaxdcjobsid="SELECT FileRowID, submissionDate FROM DCjobs WHERE submissionDate=(SELECT MAX(submissionDate) FROM DCjobs)";
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $selectmaxdcjobsid);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectmaxdcjobsid)){
        $maxdcjobsfileid=$row['FileRowID'];
        $maxdcjobsubdate=$row['submissionDate'];
    }
    $selectarchiveid="select submissionId, submissionDate from DCjobsArchive where submissionDate='$maxdcjobsubdate'";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectarchiveid)){
        $archivesubmissionid=$row['submissionId'];
        $archivesubmissiondate=$row['submissionDate'];
    }
    $update="UPDATE DCjobsArchive SET DCjobsFileId='$maxdcjobsfileid' WHERE submissionId='$archivesubmissionid'";
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $update);
}
```

Comment: completion_date is a varchar 255 as well as DCjobsFileId I just used crap as a placeholder. the insert statement works up until it hits completion_date but everything else works except the update statement

Comment: "however i will fix that later" -- famous last words

Comment: If you want to add details, edit the question, not as comments.

Comment: The `while` loops keep updating the variables, so at the end when you do the `UPDATE` they just have the values from the last rows that were selected.

Comment: But since there's no `ORDER BY` clause, it's unpredictable what order they'll select the rows.

Comment: If you're just trying to get the auto-increment IDs assigned to the rows that you inserted, you should call `mysqli_insert_id()` after each `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the IDs assigned to the rows that you just inserted, so you can fill in a foreign key. You can do that using the MySQL built-in function `LAST_INSERT_ID`.

```
function add_jobs($job_data){
    global $db_conx;
    array_walk($job_data, 'array_sanitize');
    mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO `DCjobs` ($jobfields) VALUES ($jobdata)");
    mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO `DCjobsArchive` (DCjobsFileId, $jobfields) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), $jobdata)");
}
```